# STMTHEAP on DB2/400?

Tags: operating-system, db2-400

Can someone explain to me what is the STMTHEAP on DB2/400 ?

Is it an editable value ?

Thank's

Answer (score 1):

STMTHEAP is a configuration item for Db2 LUW (Linux, Unix, Windows) not for Db2 for i.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0000277.html

Comment: Ok, Thank's very much